# SonarQube doesn't recognize custom PomCheck rule

Tags: java, sonarqube

Running SonarQube 6.4 using Java plugin 4.9.0.9858.I have written a rule to confirm that maven projects developed internally are importing a parent POM file that contains standard version numbers for various libraries. I've coded, unit tested, deployed, and activated the rule in the Quality Profile successfully.  However when I run a scan against a maven project using that Quality Profile, the rule is not fired.

I can see class `org.sonar.java.xml.XmlAnalyzer` decides which rules are fired for xml files in general and pom files in particular.  Specifically, XMLAnalyzer selects all rules that are instances of `org.sonar.java.xml.maven.PomChecks` to apply to pom.xml files.

Problem is, my custom rule *is* an instance of the class `org.sonar.java.xml.maven.PomCheck`, as follows

```
import org.sonar.java.xml.maven.PomCheck;

...snip...

@Rule( key = "UseParentPOM" )

public class UseParentPOM implements PomCheck {

...snip...
```

This "implements PomCheck" method is exactly how java-plugin supplied rules like `GroupIdNamingConventionCheck` define themselves as PomChecks - and they *are* being are selected during my scanning runs.  I've checked that I'm compiling my custom rules using the same plugin library version that the SQ installation is using.  And running sonar-scanner-debug and attaching to the running process shows my UseParentPOM rule is in fact in the visitors list XMLAnalyzer uses to search for candidate rules.  But the specific condition of "visitor instanceof PomCheck" returns false.  Ergo, my rule isn't added to the pom rules list and isn't fired when the pom.xml is scanned.

Clearly my rule class isn't the PomCheck that XMLAnalyzer is expecting, but what am I doing wrong to make it an instance of PomCheck?

**UPDATE**

Some further digging shows that the .jar file providing the class, java-frontend-4.9.0.9858.jar, is in both the base sonar-java-plugin-4.9.0.9858.jar and my custom-java-rules-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar.  My debugging runs show that SonarQube appears to spin up separate classloaders for each plugin .jar found in the extensions directory.  So there are indeed, as far as SQ is concerned, 2 'org.sonar.java.xml.maven.PomCheck' classes.  Hence my original issue.

I therefor attempted to remove java-frontend-4.9.0.9858.jar (and thus the PomCheck class) from my custom rules .jar by scoping all the sonar related dependencies as <provided>.  My hope was the resulting SQ process would then have 1 PomCheck class to rule them all.  However the actual result is SQ doesn't even start up, with the web server process failing when attempting to load my custom rule classes due to not being able to find (TA DA) class PomCheck.

I appear therefor to have reached an insoluble dilemma - if I include PomCheck in my custom .jar, SQ starts fine but doesn't recognize my custom rule as a "real" PomCheck.  If I don't include PomCheck in my custom .jar, SQ won't start at all.  So now I'm really in a quandary - pls help.

**ADDITIONAL DETAILS**

Re: Nicholas B's request, the code registering my custom rule is as follows

```
public final class MyRulesList {

...snip...

public static List<Class<? extends JavaCheck>> getChecks() {
   return ImmutableList.<Class<? extends JavaCheck>>builder().addAll(getJavaChecks()).addAll(getJavaTestChecks()).build();
}
public static List<Class<? extends JavaCheck>> getJavaChecks() {
    return ImmutableList.<Class<? extends JavaCheck>>builder()
        .add(PackageNaming.class)
        .add(LoggingLevels.class)
        .add(UseParentPOM.class)
        .build();
}
... snip ...
```

}

This code was copied straight from the Writing Custom Java Rules 101 site.  All 3 custom classes are properly registered as far as I can see - I can see them in the web console UI and add them to a Quality Gate there.  The only difference between rules PackageNaming/LoggingLevels and rule UseParentPOM is that UseParentPOM implements the PomCheck interface, not the JavaCheck.  However since class PomCheck is nothing but a wrapper around class JavaCheck, this seemed to be the correct way to register the UseParentPom class, e.g. just like any other JavaCheck.  But maybe not?

Comment: Can you update your question with more details/code about how your rule is  [registered and activated](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Writing+Custom+Java+Rules+101#WritingCustomJavaRules101-Registeringtheruleinthecustomplugin) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short: SonarJava does not support custom checks for POM files (i.e. custom *PomCheck*).

**More details**

Per [Java custom rules tutorial](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Writing+Custom+Java+Rules+101#WritingCustomJavaRules101-RuleActivation) , custom rules must be activated by feeding them to `getJavaChecks` (checked against source files) or `getJavaTestChecks` (checked against test files). The thing is that *pom.xml* files don't fall into any of those two categories, they rather belong to the 'XML files bucket' against which are checked specific rules.

A good way to visualize this is to glance at SonarJava's [*CheckList.java*](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-java/blob/f6316e328ea4e9e68a9c906e600be7cfd7c4bb58/java-checks/src/main/java/org/sonar/java/checks/CheckList.java), note the dedicated `getXmlChecks` and `getMavenChecks`. Those are the checks that are actually ran against XML files indexed by the Scanner.

**Concretely speaking**

While you have freedom to add custom rules to `getJavaChecks` or `getJavaTestChecks`, SonarJava APIs do not support adding rules to `getMavenChecks` (you can try but it'll effectively do nothing). Your overall analysis is quite on spot, but the fact is that only packages containing *api* are accessible through the classloader ([example](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-java/tree/4.12.0.11033/java-frontend/src/main/java/org/sonar/plugins/java/api)), not the case of *PomCheck*.

I'm not aware of any plans for changes on this front.

**'Outside the box thinking' suggestion**

[SonarXML](https://www.sonarsource.com/products/codeanalyzers/sonarxml.html) supports custom rules using XPath expressions (see [extension guide](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/DEV/Adding+Coding+Rules)). With a bit of XPath gymnastic, you could consider extending rule *xml:XPathCheck* - *Track breaches of an XPath rule*.

Comment: Fair nuff, I'd already gone down the XPathCheck route for some other simpler rules.  However I'll chime in here to ask the SQ team to consider adding support for custom PomChecks to the Java plugin.  Seems to me if the base java plugin itself supports doing a PomCheck, it should be possible to add a custom PomCheck as well.